# Ubuntu 20.10 2 soundcards. onboard digital and Creative AE-7. I hear sound, can't record sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I have a weird issue. I have a Creative A7 soundcard that works fine, sound through speakers, headphones etc. But I cannot record sound on any app like Audacity or OBS. If I open pavucontrol and change the output to the onboard Family 17 digital audio then I get the vu meters and can record but I can't hear the sound I am recording which makes using OBS to record gaming useless. Any ideas why I can't record the audio the Creative card is playing?

**I figured it out** through much googling and checking. My situation was I could hear sound on the analog channel but Ubuntu wanted to record on the digital channel which didn't allow me to hear the recording. This could be because I have 2 sound cards but could be a different reason. I read about creating a simultaneous device that uses all avalable devices in a single select-able device in the sound settings. You do this by installing paprefs (if a newbie is reading this that is by running sudo apt install paprefs on the command line), running it, selecting simultaneous output and then rebooting. once you do that you will have a new device you can choose that includes all output devices. Select this device in sound settings, Audacity and OBS and you are golden. Images below.

[paprefs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZfSX.png)

[Sound Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7wnm.png)

[OBS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJqHL.jpg)

Comment: If your recording in OBS, under 'advanced audio properties' for the sound source that has activity on the VU meters, what happens if you choose "Monitor and Output" in the monitoring section?

Comment: I have those set already. if I have the creative hda analog card selected so I can hear the sound the vu meters still don't register the source but if I change the source to the Family 17 digital onboard card I lose sound through the speakers (makes sense since I don't have the line plugged into the onboard card) but the vu meters register and I can record, just can't hear what I am recording unless I want to pull out my computer and plug the speakers into the onboard card which I don't want to do.